# Manually Changing Languages

Tags: php

I've got a website where the country is detected automatically and a language is set according to the country, but the users have no manual way to change it.

How can I add the following code to the code below it to make sure I can enter the following link: http://example.com/index.php?lang=de

```
//Code I want to integrate with the code below

switch ($lang) {
  case 'en':
  $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
  break;

  case 'de':
  $lang_file = 'lang.de.php';
  break;

  default:
  $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';

}

//Main Code Below

<?php

function visitor_country()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $result  = "Unknown";
    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
        {
            $ip = $client;
        }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
        {
            $ip = $forward;
        }
    else
        {
            $ip = $remote;
        }

    $ip_data = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip));

    if($ip_data && $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName != null)
        {
            $result = $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName;
        }

    return $result;
}

session_start();
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

if (isSet($_GET['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];

    // register the session and set the cookie
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;

    setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
} else if (isSet($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
} else if (isSet($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
} else {
    $lang = 'en';
}

if(visitor_country() == "Germany") {
    $lang_file = 'lang.de.php';
    //echo "Germany";
} else {

    $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
    //echo "Not in Germany";
}

include_once 'languages/' . $lang_file;

?>
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? That's what `$_GET['lang']` does.

Comment: Oh, Thanks.  For some reason it just started working.  Maybe I wasn't looking properly ;)

Comment: Just realised it doesnt work.

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't detailed enough for anyone to help you.

Comment: Im sorry, when i go to example.com/index.php?lang=de, the language just stays on English instead of changing to German and vice versa if someone in Germany was viewing the page

Comment: Please post your actual code, not in two separate parts, so we can see how you've tried to integrate it.

Comment: That is the full code.  Do you mean the language files because i don't think they are necessary.  If you are in Germany the language loads as German, anywhere else it loads as English.

Comment: Where did you add the `switch` code into the main code?

Comment: I added it above include_once 'languages/' . $lang_file; but then the country auto detection stopped working so I removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the auto-detection in the `default:` case of your switch:

```
$lang = null;
if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];

    // register the session and set the cookie
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;

    setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
} else if (isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
} else if (isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}

switch ($lang) {
case 'en':
    $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
    break;

case 'de':
    $lang_file = 'lang.de.php';
    break;

default:
    if(visitor_country() == "Germany") {
        $lang_file = 'lang.de.php';
        //echo "Germany";
    } else {

        $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
        //echo "Not in Germany";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had tried that, but it had not worked.  I ended up with a blank white screen.  Any Ideas?

Comment: I got rid of `else { $lang = 'en'; }`, since that prevented going into the default case. But if you're getting a blank screen, there may be an error. Check your error.log.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
   // get variable 'lang' is defined.
   $lang = $_GET['lang']
}
```

you reset the value of  `$lang_file` below in your code here :

```
if(visitor_country() == "Germany") {
    $lang_file = 'lang.de.php';
    //echo "Germany";
} else {

    $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
    //echo "Not in Germany";
}
```

if you remove that code it should work.